# установка плагина SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint

Tags: sublime-text-3, tslint

здесь находится плагин
https://github.com/lavrton/SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint

Installation. Первым делом говорят нужно установить SublimeLinter, если он не установлен, установил

Linter installation. далее установил tslint глобально, используя команду npm install -g tslint

Linter configuration. здесь я так понял, tslint должен выполнятся из командной строки. у меня выполняется

Plugin installation. установил плагин SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint

Settings. открыл настройки: preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings-Default, открывается json с настройками. добавил туда вот это:

```
"linters": {
    "tslint": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "excludes": [
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "config_filename": "tslint.json"
    }
}
```

в итоге получилось это:

```
{
    "default": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "tslint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [
                    "**/node_modules/**"
                ],
                "config_filename": "tslint.json"
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "python django": "python",
            "pythonimproved": "python",
            "magicpython": "python",
            "html 5": "html",
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
            "php": "html"
        },
        "tooltip_fontsize": "1rem",
        "tooltip_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/tooltip-themes/Default/Default.tooltip-theme",
        "tooltip_theme_excludes": [],
        "tooltips": false,
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

перезапустил sublime но изменений я не увидел в нем, как было, так и осталось. ошибок я тоже не увидел (если не правильно установил). изменял путь к файлу config_filename, тож не помогло. можете помочь, что не так?

Comment: **Не воспроизводится**, у меня данный линтер работает. **1)** В файл настроек по умолчанию вообще ничего не нужно добавлять, если путь к tslint у Вас по умолчанию.  SublimeLinter сгенерирует сам, что нужно. **2)** Включите [**Debug Mode**](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#debug-mode) и посмотрите, выводится ли что-нибудь в консоли от этого пакета. **3)** Если что, расширение у файлов, в которых применяется линтер, [**обязательно должно быть**](https://github.com/lavrton/SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint/blob/master/linter.py#L28) `.ts` или `.tsx`.

Comment: **4)** Если что, модуль TypeScript тоже должен быть установлен — `npm install -g typescript`. **5)** Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос пример ошибочного TypeScript кода, который `tslint` линтит из терминала, но не из SublimeLinter, и свой файл `tslint.json`, дабы я и/или другие участники смогли воспроизвести проблему у себя. // Спасибо.

Comment: ts не был установлен глобально. это решило проблему, спс